# generate vector with incremental values in matlab

Tags: matlab

Given an integer n, I would like to get the vector as follows. E.g. if `n=3`, then vector should be `[1,1,2,1,2,3]` and if `n=4`, then vector should be `[1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4]`, and so on. Is there a simple way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: How high of numbers are you likely to have for n?

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto No more than 1000, for sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses the "upper triangular matrix" function to select the needed entries from a simple repetition of the full sequence:

```
A = triu(repmat((1 : n)', 1, n));
A = A(A ~= 0)'
```

`triu` sets everything below the diagonal to zero. This approach only works if the original sequence doesn't include zeros, which of course is given for `1 : n`. Still, a better solution might be to use the result of `triu` only for indexing:

```
A = repmat((1 : n)', 1, n);
A = A(triu(ones(n)) ~= 0);
```

This is pretty fast, below 1 second runtime for n = 10,000 on my machine.

As Dennis Jaheruddin pointed out, this approach needs a bit less than twice as much memory temporarily than is needed for the result (the precise factor is 2 n / (n + 1)).

Answer (score 3):

You get a fast solution using this

```
w=ones(1,n*(n+1)/2);
w(1+cumsum(1:n-1))=-(0:n-2);
w=cumsum(w);
```

On my machine, Dennis's solution is fastest for `n<=8`, but after that this method is the fastest.

Using this benchmarking code:

```
n=2000;
N=1e6/n;

tic
for k=1:N
    A = repmat((1 : n)', 1, n);
    A = A(triu(ones(n)) ~= 0);
end
toc


tic
for k=1:N
    w=ones(1,n*(n+1)/2);
    w(1+cumsum(1:n-1))=-(0:n-2);
    w=cumsum(w);
end
toc

tic
for k=1:N
    %// Fast vector growing
    v=[];
    for t = 1:n
        x = 1:t;
        v(end+x) = x;
    end
end
toc
```

For `n=4`

```
Elapsed time is 5.688693 seconds.
Elapsed time is 3.576366 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.878887 seconds.
```

For `n=8`

```
Elapsed time is 2.985184 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.851967 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.834574 seconds.
```

For `n=100`

```
Elapsed time is 1.084404 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.352033 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.502724 seconds.
```

For `n=1000`

```
Elapsed time is 15.625361 seconds.
Elapsed time is 3.949131 seconds.
Elapsed time is 11.497764 seconds.
```

For `n=2000`

```
Elapsed time is 29.940548 seconds.
Elapsed time is 7.649394 seconds.
Elapsed time is 22.846367 seconds.
```

Comment: Hmm I wasn't planning to, but if there is a speed comparison I will write the faster loop alternative I had in mind. Wonder how it compares to the cumsum approach. -- Update: A preallocated loop is (of course) faster than a growing one, but (of course) not as fast as your vectorized solution.

Comment: Very clever alternative to the intuitive `triu` approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three other methods. I expect them to be more memory efficient than the vectorized solution by @A. Donda or @Mohsen, but of course for n = 1000 or less that is not likely a concern.

The most interesting part is the speed difference between the two methods, the second and third can also work for `n=10000` in under a second but the first is much slower!

```
n = 1000;

% Slow vector growing
tic
v=[];
for t = 1:n
   v = [v 1:t];
end
toc % 0.6 sec


tic
% Fast vector growing
v=[];
for t = 1:n
    x = 1:t;
    v(end+x) = x;
end
toc % 0.01 sec

tic
% Preallocated loop
v=zeros(n*(n+1)/2,1);
count = 0;
for t = 1:n
    x = 1:t;
    v(count+x) = x;
    count = count+t;
end
toc % 0.01 sec as well
```

Comment: The speed difference is interesting. Not sure, but you could probably make both methods faster by preallocating `v` to n (n+1) / 2 elements, but then of course you need to explicitly indicate whereto each new subsequence has to be written.

Comment: @A.Donda Actually I was in the process of doing that when I stumbled upon this. After finding the speedup by the second method I decided to stop as I would be trading speed against simplicity.

Comment: In my benchmark for `n=1000`, your `preallocated loop` approach is twice faster than your `fast vector growing` approach but still twice slower than `cumsum`.

Comment: For larger n, the difference between "preallocated" and "fast" is even smaller. I wonder why. Yet another mystery of Matlab's memory management...

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia: you win :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a sparse matrix we can do:

```
p      = 1:4;
x      = cumsum(sparse(1,cumsum(p)+1,-p)+1);
x(end) = []
```

**Result:**

```
x =

   1   1   2   1   2   3   1   2   3   4
```

The biggest advantage of this method is that it also work with unordered sequence length:

```
p      = [2 3 2 4];
x      = cumsum(sparse(1,cumsum(p)+1,-p)+1);
x(end) = []
```

**Result:**

```
x =

   1   2   1   2   3   1   2   1   2   3   4
```